# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo1.service.PersonService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo1.dao.PersonDao'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Boot Framework without any prior knowledge of the Spring Framework. I encountered this error when I am running the spring application:

The error points to the service class
PersonService.java

```
package com.example.demo1.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo1.dao.PersonDao;
import com.example.demo1.model.Person;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonDao personDao;

    // The @Autowired means that we are injecting in actual constructor. It means we are autowiring in the PersonDao interface
    // We have multiple implementation of the PersonDao interface. So to distinguish between them we use the @Qualifier
    @Autowired
    public PersonService(@Qualifier("fake") PersonDao personDao) {
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    // Here we have the option of providing the id or not
    public int addPerson(Person person) {
        return personDao.insertPerson(person);
    }
}
```

The error shows that the bean of the type PersonDao is required that could not be found. But I could not identify how to create the bean. I have used the dependency injection for the PersonDao class.
PersonDao.java

```
package com.example.demo1.dao;

import java.util.UUID;

import com.example.demo1.model.Person;

public interface PersonDao {

    int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person);

    default int insertPerson(Person person) {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        return insertPerson(id, person);
    }
}
```

FakePersonDataAccessService

```
package com.example.demo1.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo1.model.Person;

// The @Repository annotation means that this class is served as a Repository
@Repository("fakeDao")
public class FakePersonDataAccessService implements PersonDao {

    private static List<Person> DB = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person) {
        DB.add(new Person(id, person.getName()));
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
package com.example.demo1.model;

import java.util.UUID;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Person {

    private final UUID id;
    private final String name;

    public Person(@JsonProperty("id") UUID id,
                  @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

PersonController.java

```
package com.example.demo1.api;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo1.model.Person;
import com.example.demo1.service.PersonService;
// We can implement the http methods(get, put, post, delete) implementation in the controller. We can do that by using the @RestController annotation
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    // The @Autowired means that the spring boot injects actual service in the constructor
    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    // The @RequestBody annotation shows that we convert the json body that we receive from the postman to an actual Person
    @PostMapping
    public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        personService.addPerson(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your bean to a `@Configuration` class and annotate your bean with `@Bean`... and since you have multiple, use `@Bean("fake")` instead

Comment: @RobOhRob thanks for the reply. Can you suggest me any link to add the bean to the configuration file or any link I should refer to which shows how I can achieve that.

Comment: What happens when you annotate with `public PersonService(@Qualifier("fakeDao") PersonDao personDao)` ?

Comment: As R.G mentioned the Qualifier reference is just wrong and causing Spring not to find your PersonDao when trying to inject the PersonDao into your PersonService constructor. You also have the option to just remove the Qualifier annotation, which eliminates typo mistakes like yours.
But anyways, it would be more helpful if you also display the bigger picture of what you want to achieve.
Also it seems you are not using the spring controller/service/repository concept correctly (in case you were unaware of it).